# congratulation on Christmas

Tags: word-usage

Do we congratulate people for their achievements only, or does one congratulate them on occasions like Christmas too? Can one say?

> Congratulation to you on Christmas!

Comment: Related question: [Why is it Merry Christmas instead of Happy Christmas?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/90369/9161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we typically use *congratulations* in the plural, so it would be:

> Congratulations to you on Christmas!

However, to answer your primary question: No, we don’t use the word *congratulations* in this way. It may sound odd, but a word often used around special holidays is *greetings*, which is why you’ll see many cards with expressions like:

- Seasons greetings
- Greetings at Christmastime

In fact, these are even called *[**greeting cards**](https://www.google.com/search?q=christmas%20greeting%20card)*.

Congratulations are typically reserved for achievements, such as graduations, or some special occasions such as weddings. They could be used for a birthday, I suppose, although that may be regarded as humorous. The standard expression is simply, “Happy birthday!”

Answer (score 1):

No, it is conventional to wish someone a happy Christmas. You would only congratulate them if they had achieved a notable milestone in their life such as *"Congratulations on your 21st birthday"* or *"Congratulations on your promotion"*